# Why does displaying/hiding an HTML element via Javascript put it on a new line?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=214

On it there is a link "suggest a solution" towards the middle bottom of the screen.  If you click it, it calls a JS function to hide it, and show a diff element in its place.  For some reason it places the other element on the next line which looks awkward.

Would you know why this is happening? I can't figure it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<a>` tag containing the link `Suggest a solution` is set to `display: block;` This causes the breaks before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#show_existing_suggestions").hide()` / `show()` to achieve the same rather than adding the style. I tried it on Chome Developer tool and it worked as expected... Give it a try :)

Answer (score -1):

Anchors are block elements by default. You'll need to style them to be inline.

Comment: No - anchors are inline by default